# HTML form not POSTing

Tags: php, html

Im trying to post data and put it into a msql database but when i put do print_r($_POST); it shows the array as empty. I know its getting the value correctly however its not posting

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
       <script src="Scripts/menu.js"></script>
       <script src="Scripts/signup.js"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='CSS/index.css'> 


</head>

<body>

<img src="wc.png" id="wc">

<img src='restaurant.jpg' id="restaurant">
<img src='map.jpg' id="map">
<img src='mail.jpg' id="mail">
<img src='people.jpg' id="people">

<div id="window"> <div id="membersWindow"> <input type="text" id="signupUsername" value="name" placeholder="Username">

<form action="/signup.php" method="post">
<input type="password" id="signupPassword" placeholder="Password">

<input type="text" id="signupEmail" placeholder="Email"> 

<input type="text" id="signupphoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number">

<iframe src="useragreement.html" id="userAgreement"> </iframe>

<input type="submit"  id="signupSubmit">
</div> 

</form>

<div id="restaurantWindow"> Restaurant Window </div>

<!--- <div id="mapWindow"> <iframe src="https://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&amp;ll=29.817178,-95.401291&amp;spn=0.689868,1.256561&amp;t=h&amp;z=10&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
 </div> --->

<div id="mailWindow"> Mail Window </div>

</div>

<div id="banner"> <h1> Wolfeboro Connection </h1> </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Below is the php page that is getting the post however it shows array() as blank. There also isnt any errors reporting.

```
<?php
error_log(E_ALL);

if( isset($_POST) ) echo "NO POST<BR>";
print_r($_POST);



include("connection.php");



$stmt = $db->stmt_init();

if($stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO users (BusinessName, Password, Phone, Email ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

}



?> 


$(function()
{ 
alert($("#signupUsername").val());

$("#signupSubmit").click(function() {
alert("posting "+$("#signupUsername").val());

$.post( "../signup.php",
  { username: $("#signupUsername").val(),
    password: $("#signupPassword").val(),
    phonenumber: $("#signupphoneNumber").val(),    
    email: $("#signupEmail").val() 
  })
  .done( function(r)
  {
    alert("done");
  })
  .fail( funciton()
  {
    alert("fail");
  });
 });
alert("loaded");

});
```

Comment: You can also use the "HTTPFox"-AddOn for Firefox to get all requests including all GET/POST information for debugging. It's very helpful :)

Comment: Where do the jQuery and AJAX come into play?  This is just a basic HTML form from what you have shown.

Comment: ya sorry i submitted the rest of the code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `<input>` tag needs `name` attribute. it'll be used to be index in your `$_POST`, so, this input:

```
<input name="some" type="text"/>
```

will produce:

```
$_POST['some']
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp

Answer (score 2):

You have to give all `input`s a `name` property, which will add the values to the array:

```
<form action="/signup.php" method="post">
    <input type="password" id="signupPassword" placeholder="Password">

    <input type="text" name="signupEmail" placeholder="Email"> 

    <input type="text" name="signupphoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number">

    <input type="submit" name="signupSubmit">
</form>
```